# automatically sort data in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am a total newbie here trying to make my spreadsheet AUTOMATICALLY sort the data based on DATE. I've attached a photo of the spreadsheet I am using.

You'll notice a WORKDAY formula in column G. Once I've updated the Dispensed Date, the Re-order Date updates according to the formula (based on the Working Day arranged).  I then use SORT RANGE A-Z for column G to first give me the earliest date. I would desperately like to automate the SORTING RANGE bit so that once I've updated the Date Dispensed, the Re-Order Date is updated according to the formula and then automatically drops the entire row to the bottom of the list.

Where I am at the moment:

I've made the column Auto Sort using YouTube, but ONLY if I change the Re-Order date myself. It is not accepting sorting the date if I update Date Dispensed. Although it does update the Re-order date to the new date, it does not sort the data A-Z. It stays where it is. I hope I'm making some sense.

This is the code/formula I've used based on YouTube:

```
function autoSort(e) {
 const row = e.range.getRow()
 const column = e.range.getColumn()
 const ss = e.source
 const currentSheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
 const currentSheetName = currentSheet.getSheetName()

 if(!(currentSheetName === "ORDERPAD" && column === 7 && row >= 2)) return

 const range = currentSheet.getRange(2,1,currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,7)

 range.sort({column: 7, ascending: true})
}

function onEdit(e){
 autoSort(e)
}
```

[image]

Comment: The question is an exact copy of [Automatically sort data in excel](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/235173440). See [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).

Answer (score 0):

The `onEdit` function name, is the name reserved to be used for a function to be called by the on edit simple trigger, which is triggered when a user edits a cell or range using the Google Sheets user interface. The event object properties will return objects and values based on the cell or range edited by the user.

Considering the above, you need to adapt the script to work for the case when you edit the Date Dispensed, more specifically, you need to change

```
if(!(currentSheetName === "ORDERPAD" && column === 7 && row >= 2)) return
```

The above if statement stops the onEdit function execution when the Date Dispensed is edited because it's in column G, corresponding to column 6.

One way to change the above statement is

```
if(!(currentSheetName === "ORDERPAD" && [6,7].includes(column) && row >= 2)) return
```

- `[6,7]` is an array including two elements, 6 and 7.
- `includes` is the method Array.prototype.includes. If the parameter's value is included in the array, it will return true, otherwise false.

You should spend some time learning programming with JavaScript to better understand the Google Apps Script documentation and code you found on resources like the YouTube video and adapt to your specific needs.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: It worked! Mate, you are brilliant! Thank you. And thank you for the resources, i will definitely read them.